# How to clone data from a passable props on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clone

I'm creating a Multi Dropdown component in React.JS, I want to clone a variable (selectedData) from App.js into a component. But when I try to clone data there is always an error "Cannot assign to read only property 'selectedData' of object"

```
import React from 'react';
import MultiDropdown from './Components/MultiDropdown/MultiDropdown.component';
import { allOptions } from './Utils/DummyData';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  var clonedData = [
    { value: 'Normal', label: 'Normal' },
    { value: 'Angry', label: 'Angry' },
    { value: 'Love', label: 'Love' },
  ]
  return(
    <div className='app'>
      <MultiDropdown 
        data={allOptions} 
        placeholder="Select Options"
        selectedData={clonedData}
        // value={clonedData}
      />
      <button onClick={() => console.log("Selected", clonedData)}>Click to See SelectedData</button>
    </div>
  )
}
  

export default App;
```

I wanted to clone variable CloneData, that passed on selectedData, I use this function to clone data

Here's my components code :

```
export default function MultiDropdown(props: Props): React.Node {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(props.selectedData ? props.selectedData.map(opt => opt.value) : []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.selectedData = data;
  }, [data, props]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        ref={props.selectedData}
        {...DropDownProps(props, data, SelectOption)}
        onChange={selected => setData(selected.map(opt => opt.value))}
      />
      {data.map(opt => (<ListContainer key={opt} opt={opt} data={data} set={setData} />))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying cloning my variable on useEffect

Thankyou guys!

Comment: The initial problem is here `props.selectedData = data;`. You can't overwrite props values. But you have a deeper problem in understanding React.
You need to lift the state up. I recommend reading that react documentation in order to understand how to achieve what you are trying to achieve https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: But if you want a quick solution: you need to remove `useEffect`, move `useState` to `App`. And then pass `data, setData` to your `MultiDropdown` as props.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly change props that come to your component but there is a way:

You can create a `useState` to store your `clonedData` pass the state and the function that changes that state.

```js
import React from 'react';
import MultiDropdown from './Components/MultiDropdown/MultiDropdown.component';
import { allOptions } from './Utils/DummyData';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [clonedData , setClonedData] = React.useState([
    { value: 'Normal', label: 'Normal' },
    { value: 'Angry', label: 'Angry' },
    { value: 'Love', label: 'Love' },
  ]);
  
  return(
    <div className='app'>
      <MultiDropdown 
        data={allOptions} 
        placeholder="Select Options"
        selectedData={clonedData}
        changeSelectedData={setClonedData} // pass the setter function.
        // value={clonedData}
      />
      <button onClick={() => console.log("Selected", clonedData)}>Click to See SelectedData</button>
    </div>
  )
}
  

export default App;
```

Then use this `useState` hook rather than defining it in the component. Because there is no way to directly pass anything defined in the child component to the parent component